# Make sure that there's a character at the end of each line

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have file with following content.

```
This
is,
are,,,
a,,
```

I want to replace the end of the line with single comma.
If there is no comma at the end of the line then add one comma and if there are more than one comma then replace it with single comma.

output is look like this

```
This,
is,
are,
a,
```

Comment: How shall trailing whitespaces be treated? Replace commas if they are followed by whitespaces in the end of the line as well or not?

Answer (score 19):

The simplest approach is to use `sed` with in-place editing:

```
sed -i 's/,*$/,/' file
```

The `-i` makes the changes to the same file. You can use `i.bak` to create a `file.bak` backup file of the original. You can also run it without the `-i` to see the changes before they're applied. The `s/foo/bar/` is the substitution operator. It will replace the first instance of `foo` with `bar`. The `$` marks the end of the line, and `*` means "0 or more". So, `s/,*$/,/` means "replace 0 or more commas at the end of the line with one comma". If no commas are there, one will be added and if there are more than one, they will be replaced with a single one.

Some other options, for the sake of completion:

- Perl

  ```
  perl -i -pe  's/,*$/,/' file
  ```

  Same idea as the `sed` above. This is where `sed` got the `-i` idea from.

  If speed is an issue, this one will be the fastest of all the solutions here:

  ```
  perl -i -lne 'printf join ",", (grep {$_ ne ""}split(/,/) ); print ","' file
  ```
- `awk`

  ```
  awk '{sub(/,*$/,",")}1;' file >newfile
  ```

  Or, with newer versions of (g)awk:

  ```
  awk -iinplace '{sub(/,*$/,",")}1;' file
  ```
- Pure shell (slower and less efficient, only included as an example):

  ```
  while read line; do echo "${line/%,*/},"; done < file > newfile
  ```

  The `${var/%foo/bar}` will replace any `foo` from the end of the variable `var` with `bar`. Here, we're replacing everything after the last comma, so this won't work if you have multiple commas per line, **it only works on your example**. The other solutions don't have any of these limitations.

Comment: Will `sed -i 's/,*$/,/' file` add `,`, when missing?

Comment: @Motte001 yes. As I said in the explanation, that will replace *0 or more commas with a single comma*. So, if there are no commas, it will add one.

Answer (score 5):

#### In case there are possible commas in between

Slower then the `sed` option on smaller files, but *faster* on bigger files (tested on 10MB), is the python option below.

Also if there is the *possibility* of commas elsewhere in the lines, the long one- liner below will work:

```
python3 -c "ls = open('file').read().splitlines(); [print( (',').join([s for s in l.split(',') if not s == ''])+',') for l in ls]"
```

or a little shorter:

```
python3 -c "[print( (',').join([s for s in l.split(',') if not s == ''])+',') for l in open('f').read().splitlines()]"
```

...where `'file'` is the absolute path to your file, between (single!) quotes.

#### example

on a file:

```
something like, for example this
here, read this line, I added some commas,,,,,,,,
are, you convinced or not,
just say something, anything
```

...the output is:

```
something like, for example this,
here, read this line, I added some commas,
are, you convinced or not,
just say something, anything,
```

#### Explanation

```
ls = open('file').read().splitlines()
```

reads the file, splits it into lines

```
[s for s in l.split(',') if not s == '']
```

splits the line by the delimeter `,` removes the (possible) comma(s) from the end of the line

```
(',').join([s for s in l.split(',') if not s == ''])+','
```

joins the split sections, adds a comma at the end.

Comment: All of the approaches in my answer except the shell one (which is bad for many reasons) can deal with commas in between as well.

Comment: @terdon surprising result (but then again not so surprising):  if I make both the sed and python option output to a file, on *smaller* files, sed is (much) faster, but on bigger files (tested on a 10mb file), the python option is twice as fast on my system.

Comment: Probably because you're using `split` instead of a regex.